# File object created and modified property values vary from ListItemCollection and FileCollection

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, asp.net

I noticed some differences in values when calling File obj Created and Modified properties from ListItemCollection and FileCollection. Details below:

Below is some old code that fetched files from folder in FileCollection where I initialize required properties:

```
using (var spClientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, _clientId, _clientSecret))
{
    if (spClientContext != null)
    {
        List list = spClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
        spClientContext.Load(list);
        spClientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
        spClientContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
        spClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        FolderCollection fcol = list.RootFolder.Folders;

        if (fcol != null)
        {
            foreach (Folder f in fcol)
            {
                if (f.Name.Equals(folderName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    spClientContext.Load(f.Files,
                                         items => items.Include(
                                             item => item.Name,
                                             item => item.Author,
                                             item => item.ModifiedBy,
                                             item => item.ListItemAllFields["Created"],
                                             item => item.ListItemAllFields["Modified"],
                                             item => item.ListItemAllFields["FileRef"],
                                             item => item.Length));

                    spClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    FileCollection fileCol = f.Files;

                    foreach (File file in fileCol)
                    {
                        // Do Stuff
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I output the File Created and Modified date/time values I get the following:

- Created: 6/17/2021 11:40:28 PM  (Correct Date/Time)
- Modified: 6/17/2021 11:41:12 PM (Correct Date/Time)

Below is my updated code which collects files in ListItemCollection and initializes File properties:

```
using (ClientContext spClientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, _clientId, _clientSecret))
{
    if (spClientContext != null)
    {

        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();

        camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = getSiteUrlAbsolutePath(siteUrl) + "/Shared Documents/" + folderPath;

        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope="RecursiveAll">" +
            "<Query>" +
            "<Where>" +
            "<Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Eq>" +
            "</Where>" +
            "</Query>" +
            "</View>";

        List list = spClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

        ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

        spClientContext.Load(listItems,
                             items => items.Include(
                                 item => item.DisplayName,
                                 item => item.FileSystemObjectType,
                                 item => item.File,
                                 item => item.File.Name,
                                 item => item.File.Author,
                                 item => item.File.ModifiedBy,
                                 item => item.File.ListItemAllFields["Created"],
                                 item => item.File.ListItemAllFields["Modified"],
                                 item => item.File.ListItemAllFields["FileRef"],
                                 item => item.File.Length));

        spClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        if (listItems != null && listItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
            {
                if (item.FileSystemObjectType.Equals(FileSystemObjectType.File))
                {
                    // Do Stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I output the File Created and Modified date/time values I get the following:

- Created: 6/18/2021 6:40:28 AM (Incorrect Date/Time)
- Modified: 6/18/2021 6:41:12 AM (Incorrect Date/Time)

All the other File properties in the new code appearing to be correct. From what I can tell in the new code Created and Modified are outputting UTC and not recognizing time zone setting in SharePoint site settings? Or am I initializing the File properties in the wrong spot?

Thanks for any feedback and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my solution on StackOverflow which outlines two UTC to Local solutions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68030618/file-object-created-and-modified-property-values-vary-from-listitemcollection-an